# Grabbing all files in a query using Python

Tags: python

I'm processing a large amount of files using Python. Data related to each other through their file names.

If I was to perform CMD command to perform this (in windoes) it would look something like:

```
DIR filePrefix_??.txt
```

And this would return all the file names I would need for that group.

Is there a similar function that I can use in Python?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module.

```
glob.glob("filePrefix_??.txt")
```

returns a list of matching file names.